# Android Architecture Components network threads

Tags: java, android, multithreading, architecture

I'm currently checking out the following guide: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/guide.html

The networkBoundResource class:

```
// ResultType: Type for the Resource data
// RequestType: Type for the API response
public abstract class NetworkBoundResource<ResultType, RequestType> {
    // Called to save the result of the API response into the database
    @WorkerThread
    protected abstract void saveCallResult(@NonNull RequestType item);

    // Called with the data in the database to decide whether it should be
    // fetched from the network.
    @MainThread
    protected abstract boolean shouldFetch(@Nullable ResultType data);

    // Called to get the cached data from the database
    @NonNull @MainThread
    protected abstract LiveData<ResultType> loadFromDb();

    // Called to create the API call.
    @NonNull @MainThread
    protected abstract LiveData<ApiResponse<RequestType>> createCall();

    // Called when the fetch fails. The child class may want to reset components
    // like rate limiter.
    @MainThread
    protected void onFetchFailed() {
    }

    // returns a LiveData that represents the resource
    public final LiveData<Resource<ResultType>> getAsLiveData() {
        return result;
    }
}
```

I'm a bit confused here about the use of threads.
Why is @MainThread applied here for networkIO?
Also, for saving into the db, @WorkerThread is applied, whereas @MainThread for retrieving results.

Is it bad practise to use a worker thread by default for NetworkIO and local db interaction?

I'm also checking out the following demo (GithubBrowserSample): https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components
This confuses me from a threading point of view.
The demo uses executors framework, and defines a fixed pool with 3 threads for networkIO, however in the demo only a worker task is defined for one call, i.e. the `FetchNextSearchPageTask`. All other network requests seem to be executed on the main thread.

Can someone clarify the rationale?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems you have a few misconceptions.

Generally it is never OK to call network from the Main (UI) thread but unless you have a lot of data it might be OK to fetch data from DB in the Main thread. And this is what Google example does.

**1.**

> The demo uses executors framework, and defines a fixed pool with 3 threads for networkIO, however in the demo only a worker task is defined for one call, i.e. the FetchNextSearchPageTask.

First of all, since Java 8 you can create simple implementation of some interfaces (so called "functional interfaces") using lambda syntax. This is what happens in the [NetworkBoundResource](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/repository/NetworkBoundResource.java#L67-L76):

```
            appExecutors.diskIO().execute(() -> {
                saveCallResult(processResponse(response));
                appExecutors.mainThread().execute(() ->
                        // we specially request a new live data,
                        // otherwise we will get immediately last cached value,
                        // which may not be updated with latest results received from network.
                        result.addSource(loadFromDb(),
                                newData -> result.setValue(Resource.success(newData)))
                );
            });
```

at first task (`processResponse` and `saveCallResult`) is scheduled on a thread provided by the `diskIO` `Executor` and then from that thread the rest of the work is scheduled back to the Main thread.

**2.**

> Why is @MainThread applied here for networkIO?

and

> All other network requests seem to be executed on the main thread.

This is not so. Only result wrapper i.e. `LiveData<ApiResponse<RequestType>>` is created on the main thread. The network request is done on a different thread. This is not easy to see because [Retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit) library is used to do all the network-related heavy lifting and it nicely hides such implementation details. Still, if you look at the [LiveDataCallAdapter](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/util/LiveDataCallAdapter.java#L48) that wraps Retrofit into a `LiveData`, you can see that [Call.enqueue](https://square.github.io/retrofit/2.x/retrofit/retrofit2/Call.html#enqueue-retrofit2.Callback-) is used which is actually an asynchronous call (scheduled internally by Retrofit).

Actually if not for "pagination" feature, the example would not need `networkIO` `Executor` at all. "Pagination" is a complicated feature and thus it is implemented using explicit `FetchNextSearchPageTask` and this is a place where I think Google example is done not very well: `FetchNextSearchPageTask` doesn't re-use request parsing logic (i.e. `processResponse`) from `RepoRepository` but just assumes that it is trivial (which it is now, but who knows about the future...). Also there is no scheduling of the merging job onto the `diskIO` `Executor` which is also inconsistent with the rest of the response processing.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications and pointing out possibilities for improvement. I was indeed misinterpreting the annotations, i.e. that the network requests are executed asynchronously by Retrofit and only the wrappers on the main thread.